# populating a listbox from another window, but on second attempt the list is replaced instead of added

Tags: wpf

I'm building a task list application.

From my main window, I click on the add button. The program generates a new Window,and I compete the form and close it with the complete button.

My `listbox` in the main window has been populated with the tasks that I have entered.

The problem is, when I do this again, the `listbox` items are replaced with new items instead of the ones being added.

#### MainWindow.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();        
    }
    
    List<Task> allTasks = new List<Task>();
            
    
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void addTaskBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NewTaskWindow newTaskWindow = new NewTaskWindow();
        newTaskWindow.Owner = this;
        newTaskWindow.Show();
    }

    private void editTaskBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    
    }

    private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    
    }
    
    private void AddUserBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    
    }
    
    private void markCompleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void deleteTaskBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
                
    }
}
```

#### NewTaskWindow.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
    
namespace Task_Managment
{        
        
    public partial class NewTaskWindow : Window
    {
        Task newTask = new Task();

        public NewTaskWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        ObservableCollection<Task> AllTasks = new ObservableCollection<Task>();
        ObservableCollection<Task> taskList = new ObservableCollection<Task>();

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] taskType = new string[3];
            taskType[0] = "Home";
            taskType[1] = "College";
            taskType[2] = "Work";
            CataCombo.ItemsSource = taskType;
        }
        public void completeBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<Task> allTasks = new List<Task>();
            newTask = new Task
                    {
                        Title = titletxBx.Text,
                        Description = DesctxBx.Text,
                        Priority = prioritytxBx.Text,
                        Catagory = CataCombo.Text,
                        taskDate = calander.SelectedDate.Value
                    };
                
            taskList.Add(newTask);
                
            MainWindow main = Owner as MainWindow;
            main.taskListBox.ItemsSource = taskList;
               
            titletxBx.Clear();
            prioritytxBx.Clear();
            DesctxBx.Clear();
            responsibilitytxBx.Clear();
        }

        private void finishBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the TaskList somewhere, make the tasklist definition public to get acces from the main window and pass it from the main window when you load the new form:

```
    observableCollection<Task> AllTasks = new ObservableCollection<Task>();
    public ObservableCollection<Task> taskList = new ObservableCollection<Task>();

public NewTaskWindow(ObservableCollection<Task> taskList)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.tasklist = tasklist
    }
```

After that, you only need to retrieve and send it from the main to the new window

```
private void addTaskBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NewTaskWindow newTaskWindow = new NewTaskWindow(tasklist);
    newTaskWindow.Owner = this;
    newTaskWindow.Show();
    tasklist = newTaskWindow.tasklist; 
}
```

In the main window you must initialize it for the first run if not you will get an error:

```
ObservableCollection<Task> taskList = new ObservableCollection<Task>();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();        
}
....
```

Obviously this only save for the time you have the program open, when you close the program it will lose all the info. So if you are interested in that also, save in a file and load from it.